# JQuery Mobile Menu on Android menu button

Tags: android, menu, cordova, native

I'm developing a small hybrid app using phonegap in android. I want a menu to be popped up like any native app on the press of a menu hardware button on android phone. Im using Galaxy S2. I did try creating a DIV and toggling it on menubutton.

```
$(document).on("menubutton", onMenuButton);

function onMenuButton(){
        $("#sltmainmenu").toggle();
}
```

And this is my div which is not part of any page.

```
<div id="MAIN_MENU" data-role="fieldcontain" class="mainmenu">
  <select name="sltmainmenu" id="sltmainmenu" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="search">Search</option>
    <option value="logout">Logout</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How do I achieve a native app Menu Action using phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

You want to add this script to your document's head:

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", menuButtonHandle, false);
function menuButtonHandle() {
    alert("Menu button was pressed!");
}
```

For more information and examples, see

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton

Answer (score 0):

```
 KeyEvent.prototype.menuTrigger = function()
    {
      var e = document.createEvent('Events');
      e.initEvent('menuKeyDown');
      document.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
```

----------------------OR-------------------------------

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", function () { 
    alert('Menu button');
}, false);  

document.addEventListener("searchbutton", function () { 
    alert('Search button');
}, false);                      

document.addEventListener("backbutton", function () { 
    alert('Back button');
}, false);
```